# To stop asp.net looking for assemblies in GAC

Tags: vb.net, iis, asp.net-1.1

I have started working on a legacy project (ASP.NET 1.1) which was done in an old machine (which I dont have access to). And I am unaware of the development environment settings used for building this project.

Nonetheless, I am able to build the project and deploy it all well from my machine (I created the full development enviroment locally). In my machine everything works great.But some screens where one of the assembly dlls (third party dlls) are used do crash on any machine other than mine! They probably do net get the proper assembly (with matching version or something), even though when I have put all the assemblies in bin (and used the same files while adding references to the project). .NET runtime probably tries to find them in the GAC of the other computers? Or probably in my system itself it loads from GAC and not from the bin? How could I know all this? The question is it runs perfectly fine on my machine, where the assemblies are at both places - in bin and in GAC.

I am lost what I should do to so that no matter which machine I deploy the project, it should always look in bin only! Also, I dont want to change the code in any way because its a legacy code and has been working all right since ages! Just some settings e.g. maching.config or soemthing?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed all the references manually and added them again providing the path to bin directory. And it resolved the whole issue... Guess something in Visual studio was not refreshing the refrences paths provided before and removing and adding them again did resolve it.

Thanks guys.